# IIS MVC wrong root path points to localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have application running on local IIS server(not Express) over HTTPS with SS certificate

When I use

```
  <a class="logo" href="@Url.Content("/")">Application</a>
```

It points to `https://localhost` ,but it should point `https://localhost/application`
I've set up Project url in Project options to `https://localhost` and created virtual directory, I've even set up override url to same path with no luck.

The weird thing is that ActionLinks point to right paths, even the bundles are loaded correctly, is it MVC or IIS problem? What can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a relative path from the application root, using this:

```
 <a class="logo" href="@Url.Content("~/")">Application</a>
```

Note the `~` (tilde) before the forward slash.

Also, an option would be to use the Url to an action:

```
<a class="logo" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">Application</a>
```